# Ionic 2 Splash Screen takes too long about 8-10 seconds

Tags: android, ios, typescript, ionic2, splash-screen

Here's my code inside config.xml

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="HeaderColor" value="#50d2c2" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

and here's inside my app.component.ts

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      splashScreen.hide();
      statusBar.hide();
});
```

I am having a problem right now:

My splash screen takes too long. I enabled the production mode

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
enableProdMode();
```

and build/run the app using these commands:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

But still, splashscreen takes 8-10 seconds.

My target time should be 3 secondds.

What should be the solution?

I research everything on internet and apply the fixes but, no luck.
I am having this issue both on android and ios.
Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: try removing  `FadeSplashScreenDuration` & `FadeSplashScreen`.

Comment: and have this `<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen" />
</feature>`.

Comment: Thanks! but, still no luck, it also loads 10 seconds.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling platform?

Comment: yes, i tried, it also I removed node_modules and run npm install'
Still no luck

Comment: Did you try building a fresh app?

Comment: yes i tried it also, and transfer the pages . but still no luck.
Is it because of http requests?

Comment: It may be because of plugins. Do one thing AutoHideSplashScreen 
Make it true. And alert on  platform ready.

Comment: I also tried that, but another problem is blank screen shows before redirecting to login page

Comment: So, nothing is wrong with splash. Its working properly. Platform ready event is slow. Add your app.component.ts here

Comment: Meanwhile build an apk using ionic package